# Chart.js unable to render the chart with data reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I'm trying to work with chartjs-2 in order to render a bar chart with data. Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Bar, Line, Pie } from "react-chartjs-2";

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      chartData: {
        labels: ["Nike", "Adidas", "Louis", "Champion", "Yeezy", "Versace"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Sales",
            data: [34, 24, 4, 10, 18, 9],
            backgroundColor: [
              "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)",
              "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)",
              "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)",
              "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)",
              "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)",
              "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.6)",
              "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  }

  setChartData(labels1, data1) {
    //Pull from API here
    this.setState({
      chartData: {
        labels: labels1,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Sales",
            data: data1,
            backgroundColor: [
              "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)",
              "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)",
              "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)",
              "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)",
              "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)",
              "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.6)",
              "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    });
    return this.state.chartData;
  }

  render() {
    var data1 = [4, 4, 14, 10, 16, 9]
    var label1 = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth"] 
    console.log(() => this.setChartData(label1, data1))
    return (
      <Bar
        data = {() => this.setChartData.bind(this, label1, data1)}
        width = {100}
        height = {75}
        options = {{
          legend: {
            display: !this.props.displayLegend
          }
        }}/>
    );
  }
```

Whenever I run this, you can see the grid, but there are no bars (supposed to be a bar graph). If I replace the the `data` in the `render()` method with `this.state.chartData` instead of `() => this.setChartData.bind(this, label1, data1)`, it displays the chart that was created in the constructer but I want it to display the chart that was created in the `setChartData` method. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `render()` method should be a pure function, which means that it should not directly change the component state. You should either change your state in a lifecycle method (for example, `componentDidMount()`) or a custom method (event handler) that you invoke yourself at some point in the render.

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/r702nv2m3o) demonstrating this idea.

I recommend going through the [lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle) and figuring out which one fits your purpose best.